# Raspberry Pi setup

Tags: setup

I have some questions about the raspberry. Mine will be delivered in 7 work days so I might as well be asking some stuff i'm not sure about(so I am a complete beginner).

1. Is a HDMI cable optional or a **must have**?
2. I bought a Raspberry Pi B with an sd card, is there anything more I need to set the Raspberry Pi up? ( I've got a mouse and keyboard of course,the right power supply and an RCA cable,Ethernet cable)

Comment: Hi. Please browse all the questions and answers. This will give you an idea of what people are doing and what kind of problems they run into. It may give you some ideas, etc. You don't need HDMI cable you can just SSH into the Pi from another computer ... But what if you want to use the desktop? Then you need the cable and it would be nice to have... Just buy one... it cots a few bux dude! Besides that you got it all. Good Luck!

Comment: @ppumkin Thanks, yeah i'm looking around right now. I'm not really wondering for the money, but if I really dont need it to see everything than I wouldn't even use it. You're telling me if I want to use it to browse etc I do need hdmi cable?

Comment: Yes. If you want a desktop the easiest way is to use HDMI cable. It cheap, good quality (HD??) and it also transfers audio! I use allot of SSH but I still need my HDMI cable from time to time.

Comment: @ppumkin how is this a duplicate of that?

Comment: Ehhhh.. I think I failed skimming the question. I thought it had something to do with HDMI cables and SD cards like you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1a)
If you bought SD card w/ OS installed inside, maybe you don't have to use cable or monitor. Just connect Pi to your router via ethernet cable, then find what ip address assigned to Pi, then connect via SSH.

But if you want to use GUI desktop, you have 2 ways.
  i) Get a cable/converter/screen
  ii) Install x11vnc on Pi through SSH which explained above, then run x11vnc server on Pi. After running x11vnc service, you can get Pi's GUI screen through a VNC connection.

1b) Raspberry Pi has 2 different way to connect to screen/monitor/TV. HDMI and RCA, so if you have RCA cable and your screen/monitor/TV has RCA connector (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) you can use it to connect. I have a setup with RCA cable to connect my old CRT TV.

2) 
What you need;
* Raspberry Pi (Model B)
* SD card (installed OS of course)
* USB Keyboard
* USB Mouse
* RCA or HDMI cable to connect to screen/monitor/TV
* Power supply (5v/1A)

Optional;
* Wi-fi adapter (choose known verified vendor/model : http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters)
* External powered USB Hub (in case you want connect more USB devices)

**Update:**
Of course you can use converters like DVI->HDMI. But think that, HDMI is digital, RCA is analog.

I'm using a DVI-HDMI cable because my old LCD monitor uses DVI connection, but at work I'm using a HDMI->Display Port converter to connect my HP monitor with Display Port. Converters mostly works.

Comment: Thanks man this really helped me. So considering everything I listed, I dont have to buy anything extra?

Answer (score 0):

A piece of advice:

The little white square power supply that comes with your iPhone will not work. It says 1A on it but when you really try to use the 1A by adding a wi-fi adapter and camera module it will brown out on you.

Comment: I know a Iphone power supply wont work. I've done some research before asking. I know what to buy but I just wanted to know what is optional and what is necessary.